# B2C Getting list of identity providers configured for a B2C policy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a Microsoft Graph API/other API to get the list of identity providers configured for a particular B2C policy?

One extremely hack method could be to retrieve the login page itself and scrape it for the CP and SA_FIELD values. Obviously brittle. URL has the form:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=<policy>&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A51454%2Findex.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK ,currently there is no such api to get the list of identity providers configured for a particular B2C policy , if you need that feature, you could send a feedback in [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .

Comment: Thanks @Nan Yu. Feedback post is at:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19388701-add-graph-api-to-get-identity-provider-list-for-a